# Get all appRoles on an Azure AD App Registration in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

In my ASP.NET MVC Core project, I want all the AppRoles that are set up in the App Registration as a list to display in my view.

Currently I have attempted the following:

```
var servicePrincipal = await _graphServiceClient.Applications[_configuration["AzureAd:AppRegistrationId"]]
            .Request()
            .Select("appRoles")
            .GetAsync();
```

I have granted the application the API permissions `Application.Read.All` and `Directory.Read.All`, but I still get error:

> ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied 
> Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Questions:

1. Am I even on the right path to achieve what I want and just missing the correct permission?

   - Does anyone know what permission is required then?
2. Is there a different way to achieve this task?

   - I have attempted getting the roles out of the claim, but that only displays the user's roles, not all the roles that are set up on the App Registration

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like I'm late...

I test with delegated permission and application permission, both of them are ok.

for application permission, it would be easy to do it with code like below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantId ";
var clientId = "clientId ";
var clientSecret = "clientSecret ";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var res = await graphClient.Applications["azure_ad_app_object_id_instead_of_client_id"].Request().GetAsync();
var roles = res.AppRoles;
```

This requires application type of api permission:

[image]

If we want to use the delegated api permission, since this is an MVC application, we need to integrate AAD authentication into the application first. We can follow [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/Startup.cs#L32). To generally speaking, add codes in program.cs like this:

`builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration) .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi")) .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();`

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "TenantId",
    "TenantId": "TenantId",
    "ClientId": "ClientId",
    "ClientSecret": "ClientSecret",
    "CallbackPath": "/home", //don't forget to set redirect url in azure portal
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  },
```

Then inject `graphclient` into the code and use it call graph api,

```
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync() {
    var b = await _graphServiceClient.Applications["aad_app_object_id"].Request().GetAsync();
    return View();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tiny Wang. I did not accept my own answer due to having to wait some time after adding it, so I apologize if you spent time on this after I had already resolved it (using the same method you provided in the beginning). However, this is really lucky, as I can now accept your answer instead. Thank you for a thorough response!

Comment: oh, thank you very much Marc! you can go ahead to accept your solution as the answer, and I just want to post mine to be an additional for yours, I mean the part of using delegated permission. it ok to re-choose a reply as marked

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), `Application.Read.All` is the right permission to read information about an application.

I believe the reason you are getting this error is because you have assigned this permission to your application but it seems the user who's making the Graph API request does not have that permission.

Please check the permissions assigned to the user who's making the request and make sure that they have the appropriate permissions to make this request.

Comment: Of course, this might explain it, if it is trying to run this code snippet as the delegated user.
I am attempting to run the code as the Service Principal / App Registration and not the user. I guess that means I need to connect to Graph in a different way than adding ````.AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))```` to my startup.cs?

Comment: Without looking at your complete code, it would be hard to say if your solution would work. When working with downstream API, the tokens are fetched for the user for another resource (Graph API in your case) who's making the original request (probably a Web API call). If you are running the code as the Service Principal, then you should not get the error as the Service Principal already has the permission. Can you edit your question and include how you are creating an instance of `_graphServiceClient`?

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to my original question, I ended resolving the issue by using a different approach.

I used the package Microsoft.Graph.Auth to generate a credential, then connect to Graph with that credential (basically connect as my Application Registration). Here's the function:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetGraphApiClient(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Configure application
        var clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"])
            .WithTenantId(configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"])
            .WithClientSecret(configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
            .Build();

        // Create ClientCredentialProvider that will manage auth token for you
        var authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientApplication);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

        // Call Graph API
        var application = await graphClient.Applications[<"Application object ID here">].Request().GetAsync();

        List<string> appRoles = new List<string>();
        foreach (var app in application.AppRoles)
        {
            appRoles.Add(app.DisplayName);
        }
        return appRoles;
    }
```

Probably not the best way, but works, so I am happy.